# jQuery detect already rendered element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need write some function which will be detect any jquery selector: already exists in DOM or not.
How i can do that.

If element rendered it must return true, if element not rendered it must return false.

Possible selectors:

```
'<div />'  // text jquery selected will converted to $('<div />') 
$('<div />') // simple jquery selector such as jQuery('<div />')
'#somediv' or .somediv // already rendered DOM element
```

`isDomExists('<div />')` => false

`isDomExists($('<div />'))` => false

`isDomExists($('#somediv'))` => true

Comment: if($(selector).length > 0){ // dom exists }

Comment: No, $('<div />').length returns 1. It's not correct! I need check element in DOM...

Comment: If you're looking for a DIV just use $('div')

Comment: Use [$.contains](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return true for elements that are currently in the document, and selectors which match elements in the document.

```
function isInDoc(sel) {
    var $sel = jQuery(sel);
    return $sel.length && jQuery.contains(document.documentElement, $sel[0]);
}
```

Comment: really cool way: `jQuery.contains(document.documentElement, $sel[0]);`

Comment: You need to send the function a specific element but yea, that looks good

Comment: @ShannonStrutz What do you mean by specific element?

Comment: well look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/
The way you have it here, you send it a selector, the "element".

Comment: You can send it a selector, a dom element, or a jQuery object. As far as I understand that's what OP was asking for.

Comment: Yea! It looks fine! I just wanted to note that you have to send it something to work, in case OP didn't get it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check the number of parents of the node, 
nodes with no parent is not contained in the DOM :

http://jsfiddle.net/w6XZZ/

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Javascript :

```
alert($("<div/>").parent().length);
alert($("#mydiv").parent().length);
```

Comment: it's working to but i'm not sure for tag html have parent... i think the way of @Vatev better than it.

Comment: Nodes can have parents which are not in the DOM. In which case the nodes are not in the DOM too.

Comment: Yes that's true, I had not thought about that.

Answer (score 1):

`$('<div />')` **creates** a new DIV element (but does not append to the DOM). What you need instead is `$('div').length == 0`

Answer (score 0):

You could just use jquerys `.ready()` :
[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: `$('<div />').ready(function() { alert('ready??'); });` - fires after div creation (without dom append). Not good.

Comment: Wait, you want to know when an element has been created, but not in the DOM?  In what sense is that element rendered then? If its not in the DOM, its not on the page.  Improper title?

Comment: Yes, it not displayed at page... Created in DOM model but not in page nodes. I publish example what function must return in my question.